# Incremental Update for HIPPO CMS

Tags: hippocms

I am using Hippos CMS 7.9.3 community addition.I am using eclipse as an IDE.Currently we create template on DEV environment and move all repository to test environment , But this will vanish the existing content in Testing environment.Do we have any systematic way in HIPPO CMS either from UI or back-end by which I can incrementally import selected data from one environment to another without hampering the existing data

Answer (score 1):

Hippo CMS has some very decent support for incremental updates to remote instances. In practice, you should never have to remove the remote data to update an instance. The two most commonly used scenarios to get data/content/configuration/code to a remote environment are as follows:

1) You can use the Hippo CMS Console application (http://localhost:8080/cms/console). 
It offers an XML export/import functionality, which you can leverage to get changes across. It also offers a diff/patch tool, which allows you to create patches based on your project baseline.

2) For a more automated way, I would advise you to look at content bootstrapping and updater modules.
The online Hippo documentation contains some very decent guidelines/ examples on how the mechanims works and how to do this.

- [Deploying content and configuration updates](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/update/deploying-content-and-configuration-updates.html)
- [Hippo application release management](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/release-management/hippo-application-release-management.html)

Comment: I'm interested in how this works: "It also offers a diff/patch tool, which allows you to create patches based on your project baseline."